# How to execute function based on an interval of 5 seconds after the function was last called?

Tags: angularjs

I have a function(testFunction) in my controller that gets called (by callFunction) a random number of times in a random space of time. So for example, callFunction could call testFunction 10 times; waits 30 seconds; and then calls testFunction 20 times; waits 24 hours and then calls the testFunction 2 times, etc.... I would like to execute another function 5 seconds after the last instance of that function call. For example:

```
vm.testFunction = () => {
   console.log("a");
   if(some conditional statement that determines that it's been five seconds since this function was last called)
    { 
       console.log("b");
       callTestFunction2();
    }
}
```

A problem input:

```
callFunction() calls testFunction 2 times; waits 30 seconds; calls 
testFunction 3 times; waits 2 seconds; calls testFunction 10 times:
The answer should be 
aabaaaaaaaaaaaaab
```

Comment: What does this post have to do with Angular or AngularJS?

Comment: These functions are in the controller of my angular program.

Comment: @R.Richards There are angularjs wrappers for intervals and timeouts

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'll want to use `$interval` or `$timeout`

[$timeout docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) and [$interval docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)

If you wanted to call `callTestFunction2()` after 5 seconds it would look like this

```
vm.testFunction = () => {
   console.log("a");
   $timeout(function() { 
       console.log("b");
       callTestFunction2();
    }, 5000); // Delay is in milliseconds 5 secs = 5000
}
```